# Automatically combine two tables into one on Google Sheets?

Tags: automation, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Currently I have:

Sheet 2 with a table of people's times running round Track A (names in one column and times in another) and Sheet 3 with a table of people's times running round Track B (same layout). Assuming that both tracks are the same distance, I'd like to be able to have Sheet 1 combine the two tables automatically to only show each person's fastest time (as well as which track that time was on).

Comment: What do you mean automatically combine?  Would you be open to using a formula or are you dead set on having a script.  Under what circumstances should it update/recombine the two tables?

Answer (score 0):

You have three possibilities :

1) Create a Google App Script to copy multiple column in the other sheet.
 For this , you need the documentation. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

2) Use the Google Spreadsheet function "ImportRange"

3 ) Use the Query language
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage?hl=fr

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same names in the same order on both Sheets, you can do in `A1`:

```
={Sheet2!A:A}
```

in `B1`:

```
=arrayformula(if(Sheet2!B:B<Sheet3!B:B;Sheet2!B:B;Sheet3!B:B))
```

and in `C2`:

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(sign(Sheet2!B2:B-Sheet3!B2:B);{-1,"track1";0,"both";1,"track2"};2;false))
```

or (if your locale uses `,` as decimal separator):

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(sign(Sheet2!B2:B-Sheet3!B2:B);{-1\"track1";0\"both";1\"track2"};2;false))
```